# Syntax Error while adding data using SqLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am newbie to Android programming.
I'm trying to add some data to a SqLite Database.
I am adding a name and a number into the database, but I am getting a syntax error.
I checked many sites, but I hardly found any syntax error.
If anyone can give any kind of help, i will be thankful.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
        String tablecreate = "create table " + tableName + " ( " + ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + NUMBER + " TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(tablecreate);
    }

public void addContact(String name, String num) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, name);
        cv.put(NUMBER, num);
        database.insert(tableName, null, cv);
        database.close();
    }
```

And here is what the log cat says:

```
06-24 15:09:04.930: E/SQLiteLog(1426): (1) near "number": syntax error
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426): Error inserting phone number=1234567890 name=mom
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "number": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO CONTACTS_TABLE(phone number,name) VALUES (?,?)
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-24 15:09:04.980: E/SQLiteDatabase(1426):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
```

Comment: Spaces in field names will always cause you trouble. Best to just use "PhoneNumber" (without quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround `phone number` with square brackets.
Like so `[phone number]`

Do this in your CREATE TABLE, and wherever you refer this field.

---

Or, if you always use the string variable named NUMBER, do it once in your variable definition:

```
String NUMBER = "[phone number]";
```

Comment: Der I've tried it, it says no column named phone number.

Comment: Uninstall the app and re-run it. Or increase the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant value, in order to make the `onUpgrade()` method fire (it destroys and recreates the table with the proper column name).